# How to check Response-Object in SoapUI has no attachment

Tags: groovy, soapui

I'm looking for an easy way to check whether the messageExchange-Object has **no** attachment, since there isn't a specified method to do that in the interface and apparently not in the implementations either.
Of course, when there is no attachment, something like

```
assert messageExchange.getResponseAttachments().length() == 0
```

won't work, and

```
assert messageExchange.getResponseAttachments() == null
```

is of no use either. I've seen there's a method `messageExchange.getProperties()`, however the documentation doesn't say what could possibly be in there (probably response object? I'm handling Xml btw), and since I haven't found out how to do proper logging in SoapUI yet (if possible without the extension plugin), I don't know if that thing contains anything useful.

It's obviously possible to check the response for the correct error code, but I'd like to know a way to do it in Script form if just for curiosity's sake.

If it's of any difference, I'm using the basic version. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`messageExchange`](http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/model/iface/messageexchange.html) variable allows you to get the [`response`](http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/model/iface/Response.html), and from here you can access the attachments `array`.

So you can try with the follow code inside the *script assertion*

```
assert messageExchange.response.getAttachments().size() == 0
```

Additionally if you're interested in logging on *SoapUI*, you can simply use `log` variable which is in *almost* all script contexts:

```
log.info 'your message'
```

Or

```
def myMsg = 'your' 
log.info "${myMsg} message"
```

*SoapUI* use internally *log4j* so all available levels are `log.debug`, `log.info`, `log.warn`... However note that default configuration level for this scripts is `INFO`, so `log.debug` prints nothings. You can check it in `SOAPUI_HOME\bin\soapui-log4j.xml`:

```
...
<logger name="groovy.log">
     <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="GLOBAL_GROOVY_LOG" />
</logger> 
...
```

Comment: Interesting, the size()-method seems specific to groovy? Are you aware of the reason they chose to add that feature?

Comment: Originally from java `size()` is for `collections`, `length()` method for `Strings`. However you can use `length` as a property of arrays. So in this case since `Attachements` is an array you can use `size()` and `.length` but not `length()` method... (groovy additionally also adds `size()` to some objects which can contains something countable)

Comment: Yeah according to the [source code](https://github.com/SmartBear/soapui/blob/4d72d13e52f2eb87bc4b9e48feb0349feaad4e9e/soapui/src/main/java/com/eviware/soapui/model/iface/MessageExchange.java) Attachments[] seemed like an ordinary array to me. Guess groovy holds some more surprises in the future.

Comment: @styks right it's implemented as array, due use `.length` works also `assert messageExchange.response.getAttachments().length == 0`. `:)`

Comment: And now I'm even more confused because that is exactly what originally didn't want to work (so I assumed a `NullPointerException`). Bit embarrassed :D